# How to correctly mock fs/promises and ensure functions are being called in Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm trying to write unit tests in TypeScript using Jest for a module that uses `fs/promises`. I've attempted to mock the `readdir` function, but I'm running into issues where my mocked function isn't called as expected.

Here's a simplified version of my test setup:

```js
// Mock setup
jest.mock('fs/promises', () => ({
  readdir: jest.fn(),
  readFile: jest.fn(),
}));

// Relevant imports
import { calculateMetrics } from '../tradeEvaluator';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

// Test block
describe('calculateMetrics', () => {
  const readdirMock = fs.readdir as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fs.readdir>;
  const readFileMock = fs.readFile as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fs.readFile>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    readdirMock.mockResolvedValue([/*... mocked data ...*/]);
  });

  it('should skip invalid JSON files', async () => {
    await calculateMetrics('./data');
    expect(readdirMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // other assertions...
  });
});
```

When I run my test I get an error indicating that `readdir` hasn't been called, even though my `calculateMetrics` function should call it.

I get this error:

```
 >>>>   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Are there specific steps I might be missing or orderings of mocks and imports that I need to ensure to get this to work?

```bash
$ node --version 
v20.5.0

$ tsc --version 
Version 5.1.6
```

```js
// tradeEvaluator.ts
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
let optionalTicker = null;

// If a ticker symbol is provided, capture it
if (args.length > 0) {
    optionalTicker = args[0];
}

export const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp(),
    format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
      return `${timestamp} [${level}]: ${message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'application.log' })
    // new transports.Console()  // if you still want to see the log in the console
  ]
});


export async function calculateMetrics(directory: string, tickerSymbol: string | null = null): Promise<void> {
  let files;
  try {
    files = await fs.readdir(directory);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(`Error reading directory ${directory}:`, e);
    return;
  }
  if (!files || !files.length) {
    console.error(`No files found in directory ${directory}`);
    return;
  }
.
.
.
```

Config:

tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],  
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/alphalytics-data/src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],  
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/alphalytics-data/src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    roots: ['./src/'],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
  };
```

Comment: You need to mock fs not fs/promise, the string you are passing to jest.mock should match the import 'from'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mocked `fs/promises` module, so you should use `import * as fs from 'fs/promises';` instead of `import { promises as fs } from 'fs';`

The `fs` module is not mocked, so the `fs.readdir` will be the real implementation.

e.g.

`tradeEvaluator.ts`:

```
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';
// import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
console.log(fs.readdir);

export async function calculateMetrics(directory: string, tickerSymbol: string | null = null): Promise<void> {
    await fs.readdir(directory);
}
```

`tradeEvaluator.test.ts`:

```
import { calculateMetrics } from './tradeEvaluator';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

jest.mock('fs/promises');

describe('calculateMetrics', () => {
    const readdirMock = fs.readdir as jest.MockedFunction<typeof fs.readdir>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        readdirMock.mockResolvedValue([])
    });

    it('should skip invalid JSON files', async () => {
        await calculateMetrics('./data');
        expect(readdirMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77273178/tradeEvaluator.test.ts (6.105 s)
  calculateMetrics
    ✓ should skip invalid JSON files (2 ms)

  console.log
    [Function: readdir] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      constructor: [Function: AsyncFunction] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
        mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
        getMockName: [Function (anonymous)]
      }
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/77273178/tradeEvaluator.ts:3:9)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.333 s, estimated 7 s
```